# How can I push changes to remote repository, but only changes made in particular commit, leaving everything to this date at remote repository same?

Tags: git, github

If I understand it correctly, by:

```
$ git remote add github-repo <github-repo-url>
$ git checkout master                
$ git push github-repo master
```

I would be able to push changes to another repository. But that what that would do is it wold make these two repositories same, right?

In my situation:

1. I have repository 1.
2. I have almost same project at repository 2 but with slight changes and language localization.

What I would need to do instead of rewritting everything, is to leave my second repository as it is and only push updates from what is done in particular commit at first repository, so I can push only some updates, that do not affect language localization.

Is this possible somehow?

Thank you for your effort, guys!

Comment: you want to push updates from second repo to the first right?

Comment: I would like to have one repository as a "core"/"universal" repository and then second with language localization and slight changes in website graphics etc... Also another localization can come at the future. If I understand it correctly, I should do git remote add at repository 1?

Comment: If you do a `git remote add <remote-name> <url of repo 1> ` in repo 2, I think that _might_ work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some very important corrections:

- Git stores *commits*, not *changes*.  You cannot push changes, because Git does not have changes.
- Commits *are* history.

The way this works is that each commit has an ID number.  If the ID numbers were just counting up, that might be more comprehensible—but the ID numbers are hash IDs, and look random.  But those are still the IDs.

These IDs are *shared* across all Git repositories.  Regardless of how many commits any given repository has, that repository can get another commit from some other Git.  When it does, it uses the *same* ID number.  This means that each commit ID is unique, across *all* Git repositories, for all commits.  This makes it easy for each Git to know whether it has some commit: the other Git says *do you have _____?* (fill in the blank), and your Git checks the ID numbers.

Since each commit has a unique ID, each commit commit can list its *previous* commit's ID number.  That makes commits form a backwards-pointing chain.  If we draw these commits by replacing the actual hash ID with a single uppercase letter, this looks like:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` is the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  Commit `H` stores the raw hash ID of earlier commit `G`; `G` stores the hash ID of earlier commit `F`; and so on.

Each commit, meanwhile, stores a *full snapshot of every file*.  And, when you `git push` some commit, you have your Git call up some other Git and offer it that commit, by its hash ID.  The other Git checks: *do I have this commit?*  If not, the other Git asks for it—and your Git is now obligated to offer the *parent* commit.  So if you offer them `H`, and they say they want `H`, you *must* offer them `G`.  If they don't have `G` yet, and therefore want it, you *must* offer them `F`, and so on.

Note that your branch names simply store the hash ID of the *last* commit in each branch.  Hence if the *last* commit in your `master` is commit `H`, you have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

(where I've gotten too lazy to draw the commit-to-commit arrows in their correct, i.e., backwards, direction).  Note that *your* master is **yours**; some other Git repository will have *its own* name `master`, storing some hash ID.  That hash ID might be the same `H` as in your repository, but might not.

Hence:

> `git push github-repo master` ... would make these two repositories same, right?

Close, but not quite exact.  This would call up whatever Git answers the Internet-phone-number at the URL listed under your name `github-repo`.  It would then offer them the *last* commit in your `master` branch.  If they need it, it would offer them the *second to last commit*, and so on.  Once they get all these commits—all the commits needed to lead up to the *last* commit in your `master`—your Git would then ask them to set *their* master to point to `H`.

If their `master` already points to (say) commit `F`—the same hash ID you have in *your* Git—then they already have `F` and you'll send `G` and `H`, and ask them to set their master to point to `H`.  Since `H` connects back to `F`, they will probably accept this request.  You and they will now both have all the commits that are required to go from the beginning of the repository, up to and including commit `H`.

If, on the other hand, they have something like:

```
...--F--I--J   <-- master
```

where they have commits that you *don't* have, your offer will give them:

```
...--F--I--J   <-- master
      \
       G--H   [proposal: set master to point here]
```

They will say *no* because if they set their `master` to point to `H`, they'll *lose* commits `I-J`.

> What I would need to do instead of rewriting everything, is to leave my second repository as it is and only push updates from what is done in particular commit at first repository, so I can push only some updates, that do not affect language localization.

Again, Git doesn't store *changes*.  Git stores *commits*.  If they have:

```
...--F--I--J   <-- master
```

in *their* repository, and you'd like to give them a fix that you made on `H` in *your* repository, what you will need to do initially is:

- use `git remote add` to add a *name* for the URL by which you will call up their Git:

  ```
  git remote add github-repo <url>
  ```
- use `git fetch` to get *their* commits:

  ```
  git fetch github-repo
  ```

You will now have, in *your* repository, a sequence that looks like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       I--J   <-- github-repo/master
```

(The `(HEAD)` here is to remember which branch you have `git checkout`-ed.  Right now you have only one, but we're about to add one.)

That is, *your* Git adds a *new name* to your repository.  This name is a *remote-tracking name*, rather than a branch name.  It starts with the name you invented to hold the URL for their Git, in this case, `github-repo`.  Then it has a slash to separate it from the remaining part, and then it has *their* branch name.

This remote-tracking name is your Git's memory of their Git's branch name.  All remote-tracking names work this way; you probably have some `origin/*` remote-tracking names right now.  Use `git branch -r` to list your remote-tracking names.  Use `git branch -a` to list your branch names *and* your remote-tracking names.<sup>1</sup>

You can now create a new *branch name* in your repository.  This branch name is *yours* and you can call it whatever you want, although if you want to call it `master` you have the problem that you already have a branch name `master` that you're using to remember the hash ID of your commit `H`.  So you probably want some other name.  I will use the name `them` here (you should probably invent a better name):

```
git branch them github-repo/master
git checkout them
```

or, to combine it into one command:

```
git checkout -b them github-repo/master
```

You now have, in your repository:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
      \
       I--J   <-- them (HEAD), github-repo/master
```

You will now have, in your work-tree (and index as well), the result of checking out commit `J`.  This is a commit you got from them in the `git fetch` step.  It's the *last* commit in *their* `master`, and now also the last commit in *your* `them`.

You should now make changes to *this* commit.  The changes you want may well be those represented by comparing your snapshot `H` to your snapshot `G`, assuming that between `G` and `H` you made the change that you'd like to give to them.

We'll assume here that you *don't* want to give them changes you made between commits `F` and `G`.  If those changes should remain private, you'll need to be sure you do not give them commit `G`, nor any snapshot that contains changes taken from there.

You now need to *copy* the effects of commit `H`.  To do this, you can use `git cherry-pick`.

---

<sup>1</sup>For no obvious reason, `git branch -a` sticks the word `remotes/` in front of your remote-tracking names.  In fact, your remote-tracking names are *all* shortened when you see them with either `git branch -r` *or* `git branch -a`: they all have the full form `refs/remotes/remote/name`, where *`remote`* is the remote and *`name`* is the branch's name *on* that remote.  But your *branch names* are also shortened: `master` is really `refs/heads/master`.  All of Git's names—branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and others—are unified via this `refs/` thing, and then split into [various *name spaces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) to distinguish what *kind* of name each one is.

---

#### Cherry-pick copies the *changes* of a commit

We said earlier that commits don't store changes.  They only have *snapshots*.  That's true—but suppose we take two commits that are right in a row, with their two snapshots, and *compare* the two?  That is, suppose we have:

```
...--G--H--...
```

There's a snapshot in commit `G`, and another snapshot in commit `H`.  If we extract `G` to one temporary area, and `H` to another, and *compare the snapshots*, we'll see what *changed*.

That's what `git diff` does, for instance: `git diff <hash-of-G> <hash-of-H>` will extract the two snapshots and compare them and tell you what *changed*.  That's what `git log -p` does too, and that's what `git show <hash>` does: they both find the *parent* of a commit, compare the parent to the commit, and show you what *changed*.

The cherry-pick command makes use of this.  By comparing the parent and child commits, cherry-pick can see what *changed*.  Then it can apply those *same* changes to your *current* commit.  So, given this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
      \
       I--J   <-- them (HEAD), github-repo/master
```

and your work-tree and index matching existing commit `J`, you can run:

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-H>
```

or:

```
git cherry-pick master
```

and get Git to *compare* `G` vs `H`, see what changed, and make the *same* changes now and commit them.<sup>2</sup>  If all goes well, the result is:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
      \
       I--J   <-- github-repo/master
           \
            H'  <-- them (HEAD)
```

where `H'` is a sort of copy of `H`: `J` vs `H'` show the same *changes* as `G` vs `H`.  The cherry-pick command copies the commit log message from `H`, too.

---

<sup>2</sup>This comparison actually uses Git's *merge machinery*.  Git will not only compare `G` vs `H`, but also compare `G` vs `J`, and then *merge* these diffs.  The effect, though, is almost the same as just applying the `G`-vs-`H` patch to commit `J`.

---

#### We're now ready to `git push`

Now that we have commit `H'` as the *last* commit of our branch `them`, we can use `git push` to send this commit—`H'`—to the Git over at `github-repo`.  To do this, we'll run:

```
git push github-repo them:master
```

Our Git will call up their Git, using the URL stored in the name `github-repo`.  We'll now offer them commit `H'`: the one identified by our branch name `them`.  They will not have this commit, so they will say *please send that one*.  We'll immediately offer them commit `J` because that's the parent commit of `H'`, but they have `J`, so they will say *no thanks, I have that one already*.

Hence, we'll just send the one commit that we wanted to send.

Now that they have `H'`, we'll ask them to set *their* `master`.  That's what `them:master` is about, in this `git push` command: we choose the *commits to send* from our `them`, then ask them to *set* **their** `master`.  Since `H'` just adds on to existing commit `J`, they can accept this request.  Assuming they *do* accept this, they will have, in their repository, the sequence:

```
...--F--I--J--H'  <-- master
```

and our Git will update our memory of their `master` so that *we* have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
      \
       I--J--H'   <-- them (HEAD), github-repo/master
```

and we're all good now—unless, perhaps, we'd like to add to *our* `master`.  (In which case, we can just `git merge github-repo/master` at this point.  There are a lot of options here and what to do depends on how you want to work with this.)